# lipschitz property of the derivative of a convex function

Tags: convexity

Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R)$ be a convex function. Suppose the equation

$$f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)-(f'(x),\Delta x) \leq A|\Delta x|^2$$

holds for some constant $A>0$, any $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and any sufficiently small $\Delta x\in \mathbb R^n$. Is it true that the derivative $f'(x)$ must be a (locally) lipschitz function?

Only case $n>1$ is interesting for me (case $n=1$ can be easily verified).

Comment: Cross-posted to MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116860/lipschitz-property-of-the-derivative-of-a-convex-function

Comment: In case $f$ is $C^2$, then the restriction to convexity can be dropped, and in fact, you can show an iff.

Comment: Please don't crosspost between here and MSE, without an explanation.